# Can i predict and evaluated model with the whole dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, data-science, convolution, cross-validation

I split the dataset into train and test of 80-20 ration respectively. I predicted and evaluated with test dataset. And my question is can we evaluate and predict model with the whole dataset before that I shuffle entire dataset. Can we do that? If not, why should not we do that? what is wrongdoing like that?

Answer (score 0):

Data Snooping is the quick answer what you are looking for. 
In other words, your model would seem outperforming on your test data if it was trained on 100% data first. Model would become an overfitted model that basically would predict seen data with higher accuracy however would fail to do so with any sort of unseen test data.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, however it would result in overfitted model. You can try k fold cross validation method in stead.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the whole dataset for training, the model will fit to all the variances in data (overfitting). As a result, the performance of your model on similar data will be high. However, the model will exhibit low performance on unseen data with a different distribution compared to your training dataset. One way to prevent this is to: a) split your data into training, validation, and testing datasets (see the note below), b) apply k-fold cross-validation on training and validation splits, c) verify the performance of your models from step b on the third split (test dataset). 
Note: There is no consensus on the naming of the splits. Some sources name them training-validation-testing while others use training-testing-validation.